# Flutter - fill table with dyanmic data

Tags: flutter

In my class, I have a variable named `report`, that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "my type",
    "name": "Report 1",
    "client_name": "John",
    "website": "john.com",
    "creation_time": "2019-03-12T22:00:00.000Z",
    "items": [{
            "id": 1,
            "report_id": 1,
            "place": "Kitchen",
            "type": "sometype",
            "producer": "somepro",
            "serial_number": "123123",
            "next_check_date": "2019-03-19",
            "test_result": "Verified",
            "comments": "some comments"
        }]
    }
```

I want to show the list of `items` in a table with flutter.

So far, I just created a static table as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(report['name'])),
      body: Container(
        child: Table(children: [
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Text("TITLE 1"),
                    Text("TITLE 2"),
                    Text("TITLE 3"),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Text("C1"),
                    Text("C2"),
                    Text("C3"),
                  ])
        ])
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Couldn't find any examples of how to fill the table rows (the titles can stay static) with my JSON `items` list.
Each row should be an item from the `items` JSON array.

Any idea?

Comment: so you need each item in the json array to create a table row or what?

Comment: Yes. @SamiKanafani. Il update the question to make it clear

Comment: yes please update the question

Answer (score 9):

You can map `items` to `TableRow`s. Don't forget to end with `toList()`.

For example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(report['name'])),
        body: Container(
            child: Table(
                children: (report['items'] as List)
                    .map((item) => TableRow(children: [
                          Text(item['id'].toString()),
                          Text(item['report_id'].toString()),
                          Text(item['place']),
                          // you can have more properties of course
                        ]))
                    .toList())));
  }
```

If you want the static titles that you mentioned, you could use `insert` on the list you create above, and then you have:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var list = (report['items'] as List)
        .map((item) => TableRow(children: [
              Text(item['id'].toString()),
              Text(item['report_id'].toString()),
              Text(item['place']),
              //...
            ]))
        .toList();
    list.insert(
        0,
        TableRow(children: [
          Text("TITLE 1"),
          Text("TITLE 2"),
          Text("TITLE 3"),
          //...
        ]));
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(report['name'])),
        body: Container(child: Table(children: list)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an ItemBuilder. You can find a good example of flutter ItemBuilders [here](https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb) and [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list). Examples here use the ListView builder though.